# Client can not be authenticated, got HTTP status 404 - Laravel, Redis, Socket.io

Tags: laravel-5, socket.io, websocket, redis

Intento implementar websocket en un proyecto laravel 5.7 pero tengo un problema, no reconoce la autenticación en un canal privado, al ejecutar el comando `laravel-echo-server start` me arroja el siguiente error

```
    [2022-09-19T13:40:58.059Z] - Preparing authentication request to: http://127.0.0.1:8000
[2022-09-19T13:40:58.060Z] - Sending auth request to: http://127.0.0.1:8000/broadcasting/auth

⚠ [2022-09-19T13:40:59.574Z] - 7zW41_-XLRJ82D5SAAAA could not be authenticated to private-message-channel.1
{
    "message": "",
    "exception": "Symfony\\Component\\HttpKernel\\Exception\\NotFoundHttpException",
    "file": "C:\\wamp64\\www\\catastro_sabanalarga\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\RouteCollection.php",
    "line": 179,
    "trace": [
        {
            "file": "C:\\wamp64\\www\\catastro_sabanalarga\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Router.php",
            "line": 636,
            "function": "match",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Routing\\RouteCollection",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "C:\\wamp64\\www\\catastro_sabanalarga\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Router.php",
            "line": 625,
            "function": "findRoute",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Routing\\Router",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "C:\\wamp64\\www\\catastro_sabanalarga\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Router.php",
            "line": 614,
            "function": "dispatchToRoute",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Routing\\Router",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "C:\\wamp64\\www\\catastro_sabanalarga\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel.php",
            "line": 176,
            "function": "dispatch",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Routing\\Router",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "C:\\wamp64\\www\\catastro_sabanalarga\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline.php",
            "line": 30,
            "function": "Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\{closure}",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "C:\\wamp64\\www\\catastro_sabanalarga\\vendor\\fideloper\\proxy\\src\\TrustProxies.php",
            "line": 57,
            "function": "Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "C:\\wamp64\\www\\catastro_sabanalarga\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php",
            "line": 163,
            "function": "handle",
            "class": "Fideloper\\Proxy\\TrustProxies",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "C:\\wamp64\\www\\catastro_sabanalarga\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline.php",
            "line": 53,
            "function": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "C:\\wamp64\\www\\catastro_sabanalarga\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\TransformsRequest.php",
            "line": 31,
            "function": "Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "C:\\wamp64\\www\\catastro_sabanalarga\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php",
            "line": 163,
            "function": "handle",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\TransformsRequest",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "C:\\wamp64\\www\\catastro_sabanalarga\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline.php",
            "line": 53,
            "function": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "C:\\wamp64\\www\\catastro_sabanalarga\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\TransformsRequest.php",
            "line": 31,
            "function": "Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "C:\\wamp64\\www\\catastro_sabanalarga\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php",
            "line": 163,
            "function": "handle",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\TransformsRequest",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "C:\\wamp64\\www\\catastro_sabanalarga\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline.php",
            "line": 53,
            "function": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "C:\\wamp64\\www\\catastro_sabanalarga\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\ValidatePostSize.php",
            "line": 27,
            "function": "Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "C:\\wamp64\\www\\catastro_sabanalarga\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php",
            "line": 163,
            "function": "handle",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\ValidatePostSize",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "C:\\wamp64\\www\\catastro_sabanalarga\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline.php",
            "line": 53,
            "function": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "C:\\wamp64\\www\\catastro_sabanalarga\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\CheckForMaintenanceMode.php",   
            "line": 62,
            "function": "Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "C:\\wamp64\\www\\catastro_sabanalarga\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php",
            "line": 163,
            "function": "handle",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\CheckForMaintenanceMode",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "C:\\wamp64\\www\\catastro_sabanalarga\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline.php",
            "line": 53,
            "function": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "C:\\wamp64\\www\\catastro_sabanalarga\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php",
            "line": 104,
            "function": "Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "C:\\wamp64\\www\\catastro_sabanalarga\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel.php",
            "line": 151,
            "function": "then",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "C:\\wamp64\\www\\catastro_sabanalarga\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel.php",
            "line": 116,
            "function": "sendRequestThroughRouter",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "C:\\wamp64\\www\\catastro_sabanalarga\\public\\index.php",
            "line": 55,
            "function": "handle",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "C:\\wamp64\\www\\catastro_sabanalarga\\server.php",
            "line": 21,
            "function": "require_once"
        }
    ]
}
Client can not be authenticated, got HTTP status 404
```

Otra de las cosas que he estado probando es que la ruta `http://127.0.0.1:8000/broadcasting/auth` arroja un 404 al intentar acceder a ella pero yo descomenté el provider en mi archivo app.php, se supone que al descomentar este servicio deberia laravel añadir la ruta anterior mencionada pero tampoco se encuentra al ejecutar el comando `php artisan route:list`

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este sería mi laravel-echo-server.json

```
    {
    "authHost": "http://127.0.0.1:8000",
    "authEndpoint": "/broadcasting/auth",
    "clients": [],
    "database": "redis",
    "databaseConfig": {
        "redis": {},
        "sqlite": {
            "databasePath": "/database/laravel-echo-server.sqlite"
        }
    },
    "devMode": true,
    "host": "127.0.0.1",
    "port": "6001",
    "protocol": "http",
    "socketio": {},
    "secureOptions": 67108864,
    "sslCertPath": "",
    "sslKeyPath": "",
    "sslCertChainPath": "",
    "sslPassphrase": "",
    "subscribers": {
        "http": true,
        "redis": true
    },
    "apiOriginAllow": {
        "allowCors": false,
        "allowOrigin": "",
        "allowMethods": "",
        "allowHeaders": ""
    }
}
```

¿Cómo puedo solucionar este problema?

Answer (score 0):

Solución a mi problema.

Me tocó ejecutar el siguiente comando `php artisan config:cache` y así la ruta `broadcasting/auth` aparecería en mi `php artisan route:list` después de esto tendría el siguiente error en mi laravel-echo-server

```
Client can not be authenticated, got HTTP status 419
```

para solucionar este problema añadí en mi head.blade.php el token csrf de mi proyecto

```
<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
```

ejecuté nuevamente el comando `php artisan config:cache` y ya mi aplicación podría escuchar mis peticiones.